# Node.js ReverseProxy unable to connect to API (Windows 10)

Tags: node.js, windows, express, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I am working on a Node, Express, Mongodb, React/Redux app that uses http-proxy to create a proxy server that then connects to my API which contains server logic.

When trying to connect to my API Server thru my app server proxy I am receiving these errors:

[image]

[image]

My Mongodb server is running along with webpack but when trying to start the Node Api server, it will shut down immediately though it had been working fine previously until I added session code. My intuition is that it may actually be a Windows issue (story of my life). You can find my proxy and api code below.

My Node proxy:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
//PROXY BELOW
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')



var app = express();

//PROXY TO API
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target:'http://localhost:3001'
});
app.use('/api', function(req,res){
    apiProxy.web(req,res);
})
//END PROXY

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'public','index.html'))
})

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

My Node API Server:

```
var express = require('express');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)


var app = express();

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//APIS

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bookshop');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bookshop');
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'#MongoDB - connection error'))
//SET UP SESSIONS must be after mongodb connection

app.use(session({
    secret:'mySecretString',
    saveUninitialized:false,//record session only if user adds product to cart
    resave:false,//session wont be resaved if didnt change
    cookie:{maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2},//two days in milliseconds
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: db,ttl:2 * 24 * 60 * 60})//time to leave 2 days 24 hours 60 minutes 60 seconds
}))
//SAVE SESSION CART API

app.post('/cart',function(req,res){
    var cart = req.body
    req.session.cart = cart
    req.session.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
        res.json(req.session.cart)
    })
})

//GET SESSION CART API

app.get('/cart', function(req,res){
    if(typeof req.session.cart !==undefined){
        res.json(req.session.cart)
    }
})

//END SESSIONS


var Books = require('./models/books.js')

///POST BOOKS API
app.post('/books',function(req,res){
    var book = req.body;

    Books.create(book,function(err,books){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
        res.json(books)
    })
}); 

//GET BOOKS

app.get('/books',function(req,res){
    Books.find(function(err,books){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
        res.json(books)
    })
})

//DELETE BOOKS
app.delete('/books/:_id',function(req,res){
    var query = {_id:req.params._id};

    Books.remove(query,function(err,books){
        if (err){
            throw err
        }
        res.json(books)
    })
})

//UpdateBooks(Not used in app) - uses put request
//check EB


//END APIS

app.listen(3001,function(err){
    if(err){
        return console.log('API SERVER ERROR', err)
    }
    console.log('API Server is listening on http://localhost:3001')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid assumption on my part. Nothing to do with Windows:

Problem was this line:

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bookshop');
```

When it should of been this:

var db = mongoose.connection;